# how to get previous cummax duration in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need following three values grouped by name column.

1. previous cummax value at the new max row
2. duration of previous cummax
3. minimum value in previous cummax duration

[image]

I think this needs `apply` method, but I want it to be fast as possible because I have lots of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby` with `merge` after `shift`

```
s = df.groupby(['name','cummax']).value.agg(['min','max','count']).shift()
out = df.merge(s.reset_index())
out
   cummax name  value  min  max  count
0       1    a      1  NaN  NaN    NaN
1       5    a      5  1.0  1.0    1.0
2       5    a      3  1.0  1.0    1.0
3       8    a      8  3.0  5.0    2.0
4       8    a      6  3.0  5.0    2.0
5       9    a      9  6.0  8.0    2.0
```